# Facebook app token to be revoked after the 30th of April 2015?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I work on a legacy iOS app, which uses Facebook SDK to let user login and publishes on user's behalf likes and posts on the wall. It requests `email, publish_actions, user_likes` permissions.

The app already has a valid app token and worked fine with Facebook SDK v3.13, pointed to Graph API v1.0.

Recently I have upgraded it to Facebook SDK v3.23 with Graph API v2.2.
Facebook's upgrade guide (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v1tov2) says:

> Once you are defaulted to Graph API v2.0, you should test all possible
>   features to ensure full functionality. <...> If your app is fully functional
>   after defaulting to Graph API v2.0, you need to go through Login
>   Review before April 30th, 2015.

What happens if I refuse to go through review?

Will the older ("v1.0") / newer ("v2.2") builds of the app be still functional after 30/05/2015?

Will the users be able to log in and like/post/share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V1.0 will be gone completely after April 2015, and all permissions that need review will stop working if they did not get approved.

Comment: So Facebook will look at my app token, check that it was created and approved in "v1.0 era" and prohibit any (specific, like publish actions) calls from my app?

Comment: And the adjacent question, will Facebook after approve give me new app token or the token will remain the same, but FB will just mark somewhere in DB that my this token is legit to work with new Graph API?

Comment: the token should still work, if it´s an extended one and still valid, i guess. just make sure every permission is approved before end of april and you should be fine.